# MYsql union with exists statement

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

So i've got a fairly complicated sql statement merging ten tables into one table based on requirements.

A sample of the results (only consists of the essential required for this question)

```
Unique | date | amount | Table
12345  | 10/2 | 200    |   1
12345  | 10/2 |  20    |   2
23456  | 10/3 | 100    |   3
```

My question is, since the unique is the same for the first 2 rows, but from different tables, how can i merge them together so it becomes this?

```
Unique | date | amount | Table
12345  | 10/2 | 220    |   1 (Don't really care about the table number)
23456  | 10/3 | 100    |   3
```

This is a sample of my statement

```
(SELECT unique, dates, amt, tbl FROM ..... WHERE ....) 
UNION 
(SELECT unique, dates, amt, tbl FROM ..... WHERE ....) ORDER BY dates ASC
```

Would be great if it could be done via MYsql, if not, answers in PHP / VB.net would also be accepted. All help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your query with a group by using a group_concat to grab all the table names. For example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T1,T2,T3;

CREATE TABLE T1(UNIQUEID  INT, DT DATE, AMT INT);
CREATE TABLE T2(UNIQUEID  INT, DT DATE, AMT INT);
CREATE TABLE T3(UNIQUEID  INT, DT DATE, AMT INT);

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'2017-01-01',10),(1,'2017-02-01',10),(2,'2017-01-01',20);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,'2017-01-01',10),(3,'2017-01-01',10),(4,'2017-01-01',20);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES(2,'2017-01-01',10),(5,'2017-01-01',10),(4,'2017-01-01',20);

SELECT  UNIQUEID,DT,SUM(AMT) SUMAMT,SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(TNAME),1,2)
FROM
(
SELECT 'T1' TNAME, UNIQUEID, DT,AMT FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T2' TNAME, UNIQUEID, DT,AMT FROM T2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T3' TNAME, UNIQUEID, DT,AMT FROM T3
) S
GROUP BY UNIQUEID,DT;
```

Result

```
+----------+------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| UNIQUEID | DT         | SUMAMT | SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(TNAME),1,2) |
+----------+------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|        1 | 2017-01-01 |     20 | T1                              |
|        1 | 2017-02-01 |     10 | T1                              |
|        2 | 2017-01-01 |     30 | T1                              |
|        3 | 2017-01-01 |     10 | T2                              |
|        4 | 2017-01-01 |     40 | T3                              |
|        5 | 2017-01-01 |     10 | T3                              |
+----------+------------+--------+---------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The Group_concat can be ordered if you wish and if you leave out the substring then you could print all table names.
It's not worth using a union statement without the all clause since mysql will attempt to dedupe and you don't really want to.